# Error Code: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 second

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

hello here is my c# query for an insertion but i have this error
 Error Code: 1136
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
i already specified the différents column i wanted to insert data into but it still given the same error
 please help me

```
req = "INSERT INTO fgm_pastor" +
                    "(matriculePastor, " +
                    "pastorName," +
                    " pastorSurname, " +
                    "pastorBirthdayDate ," +
                    "birthdayPlace," +
                    " pastorFathername," +
                    " pastorMothername," +
                    " pastorSexe," +
                    " pastorPhone," +
                    " pastorEmail," +
                    " dateConversion," +
                    " workBeforeBibleSchool," +
                    " rankProbation," +
                    " areaOfCalling," +
                    " nberYearArea," +
                    " nbreYearDistrict" +
                    ", martialSituation," +
                    " nationality," +
                    " pastorAdresse," +
                    " photoProfil," +
                    " raisonIndispoMissionnaire," +
                    " id) VALUES('"
                    + this.matricule +
                    "','" + this.name +
                    "','" + this.surname + 
                    "','" + this.dateOfBirth + 
                    "','" + this.pastorPlaceOfBirth + 
                    "','" + this.pastorFotherName +
                    "','" + this.pastorMotherName + 
                    "','" + this.gender +
                    "','" + this.tels +
                    "','" + this.email +
                    "','" + this.conversionDate +
                    "','" + this.professionBeforeBibleschool +
                    "','" + this.rankProbation +
                    "','" + this.areaOfCall +
                    "'," + this.numberYearInArea +
                    "," + this.numberYearDistrict + 
                    ",'" + this.martialStatus + 
                    "','" + this.country +
                    "','" + this.pastorAdresse +
                    "','" + this.picture + 
                    "','" + this.raisonIndisp +
                    "'," + this.id + ")";
```

i wand to insert in fgm_pastor

here is my table structure

CREATE TABLE `fgm_pastor` (
    `matriculePastor` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorSurname` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorBirthdayDate` DATE ,
    `birthdayPlace` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorFatherName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorMotherName` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorSexe` CHAR (3),
    `pastorPhone` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorEmail` VARCHAR (180),
    `dateConversion` DATE ,
    `workBeforeBibleSchool` VARCHAR (180),
    `rankProbation` VARCHAR (180),
    `areaOfCalling` VARCHAR (300),
    `nberYearArea` INT (11),
    `nbreYearDistrict` INT (11),
    `martialSituation` VARCHAR (180),
    `nationality` VARCHAR (180),
    `pastorAdresse` VARCHAR (300),
    `photoProfil` TEXT ,
    `isActif` TINYINT (1),
    `raisonIndispoMissionnaire` TEXT ,
    `isDelete` INT (1),
    `id` INT (11)
);

Comment: This is caused by SQL expecting the full list of columns of the table.  You should insert NULL into the columns you don't want to insert data into.  And as Gordon says, you really should learn to use parameters.  Probably worth looking into stored procedures too, you can re-use the same insert query but only inserting the columns you want that way.

Comment: thank you for you anwsers i will try to put all column i the request